# Cannot get parameter in static method in apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public void tillId(){
        String strId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fillID');
        System.debug('strId ::'+strId); 
    }
```

Result is strId :: 8G1xcdmrRxSF2kaX098j7A

```
public Static void tillId(){
        String strId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fillID');
        System.debug('strId ::'+strId); 
    }
```

Result is strId :: null

how i get values of paramter in static mathod ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it didn't work?

Comment: As your code sits in the question there are not issues and it will debug the value of the fillId URL parameter if it exists. You are going to have to provide more information (Like the code that is actually not working) and what error message if any you receive [Ask]

Comment: It tends to not be a good idea to use static variables in a vf page controller since they will never change for that execution and will most likely be null most of the time..

Comment: @ParthNaik - HOW are you calling `getId();`

Comment: its just an example , sorry u updated !

Answer (score 2):

I find myself unable to find any documentation to back this claim up, but experience tells me that the `{!}` syntax can only be used to call instance methods of the visualforce page's controller (or extension/s).

It's probably due to the trickery that Salesforce implements in the back-end so that we don't need to specify if a method is an action method (something like `save()`), a getter/setter method (like `getMyField()`), or if the method is defined on the controller or on an extension (Salesforce magic makes it 'just work').

Static methods are not instance methods (that is to say, you can/must call a static method by using the name of the class, rather than an instance of that class).

If you have the following class

```
public class MyClass{
    static public void myMethod(){}
}
```

The following won't work

```
MyClass instanceOfMyClass = new MyClass();
instanceOfMyClass.myMethod();
```

There's more to it than this, but when you're using the `{!}` syntax in visualforce, it's basically trying to execute `instanceOfMyClass.myMethod()`.

### The takeaway

Getters and Setters used in visualforce pages cannot be static methods, as you've found out.

Comment: can you just simple help me that how i can used my non static variable in static mathod.